# What exactly does the expected HTTP response for a Reverse-AJAX request look like?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-headers, http-get, reverse-ajax, ajax-push

I'm trying to implement a simple Web Service (running on an Arduino board using an Ethernet shield) that can provide (push) information to a subscribed client by means of Reverse-AJAX. 
The web service hosts a single web page that presents information from a (2D-LIDAR) sensor connected to that server board. Whenever the sensor output changes (very frequently and rapidly) the clients viewing that page should be instantly updated. For this application Reverse-AJAX / AJAX Push seems to be the option of choice, however I'm struggling to get the server part working.
This is what's in my aforementioned web page to "listen" for updates:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.multipart = true;
xhr.open( 'GET', 'push', true) ;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    processEvents( window.JSON.parse( xhr.responseText ) );
  }
}
xhr.send( null );
```

I'd like to keep the XmlHttpRequest running forever and have it call the processEvents function whenever a chunk of (JSON) data comes in from the server side. However I'm not sure what the server response, especially the HTTP response header should look like to make this work as expected.
Whenever I have the server send a HTTP response header like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Content-Length: 100\r\n
Content-Type: text/json\r\n
\r\n
```

the XmlHttpRequest finishes after receiving exactly one "chunk" of data. I also tried without "Content-Length" header, but "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=..." or "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" but both never happened to fire processEvents, supposedly because the browser was waiting for the response to complete, whatever that means.

I'm therefore looking for a working example of such a HTTP Response to an AJAX-Push request. What does a HTTP Response generally need to look like to be accepted by the indefinitely running XmlHttpRequest and to fire processEvents whenever new data arrives?

Btw. I tried those things using Firefox 64.0.

Answer (score 0):

if you a looking for a low latency http based comm you should take a look at websockets. Your xmlhttp with Post method will have a high latency of about 50 milliseconds , trust me, I tried to develop a rgb controller based on a rainbow color picker before, either sync and asynchronous post methods wasn’t working well for me, the script just hold waiting for a response.

Now to answer you question specifically, download postman, a software that allows you to simulate all the http methods requests and headers you wish to. Also gives you the code to implement in many languages, and don’t forget f12 on chrome > network tab, this way you can check how the output of or http requests are being handled